# Проблема с выводом в Listbox list<long> через .Items.Add в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#

Мне нужно выводить значения в lostbox из второго потока  в цикле для этого использую

```
 BeginInvoke(new Action(() => listBox6.Items.Add("id" + idC[i4])));
```

`idC` это  `list<long>` в нем N элементов

Периодически происходит ошибка

> Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным
>   числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции. Имя
>   параметра: index"

При этом index листа находится на последнем элементе, то есть  idC.count = 34 и i4=34;

И это происходит раз в несколько итераций

Comment: Если длина списка 34, то последний индекс равен 33, т. к. индексы от нуля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeginInvoke()` запускает `Action` асинхронно на ГУИ-потоке. Причём, начало выполнения `Action` может произойти, даже через какое-то время, т.к. ГУИ-поток может быть занят. За это время, вы вероятно успеваете поменять значение переменной, но не успеваете расширить коллекцию.

Два варианта решения, выбирайте, какой лучше подойдёт.

Используйте `Invoke()` вместо `BeginInvoke()`. В таком случае, после вызова ваш фоновый поток будет ждать, когда ГУИ-поток выполнит `Action` и лишь затем перейдёт к следующей инструкции.

Используйте отдельную переменную для передачи параметра в `Action`.

```
var x = idC[i4];
BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>  listBox6.Items.Add("id" + x)));
```